# Rails saving data from associated form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, netzke

How can I get the data from an associated form and insert it to the associated table from the main model?

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :account, foreign_key: "acc_sup_id", :autosave => true   
  self.primary_key = 'sup_id'  
end  

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :supplier, foreign_key: "acc_sup_id"  
  self.primary_key = 'acc_id'  
  self.table_name = 'accounts'  
end
```

I am having a combined form for Supplier and Account. When I submit I need to find a way to insert the corresponding values to Supplier and Account. The problem is Supplier values is inserting properly but not Account.

I have asked the same question in several forums, groups and even in stack but nobody seems to give a convincing answer.

Answer (score 0):

The basic strategy is to first look at what params are being submitted when the form is submitted.  You could add a line in the controller action such as `raise params.inspect` to see that.  Make sure that those paras contain all the data you need; if not then there is some problem in the view that generates that form.

Once you have all the data getting to the controller action, then you need to change the controller action so that is properly interprets all the data and puts it into the correct models.

I cannot give any more specific advice unless you show the code for your view, the result from doing `params.inspect`, and the code for the controller action that takes the data.

Comment: I am using netzke for my form view and in my controller there is no code. When I did **raise self.inspect** within the model I got all the values inside Parameters { }. I can give any amount of clarification required to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Let's assume that there are `orders` and `customers` tables and that you want to perform CRUD operations on customers from orders form.

Customer model is very simple

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

`Order` model must provide virtual attributes for all customer's attributes (`attr_accessor` construct). CRUD for `customers` is provided through callbacks. Validations can be used as well.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :customer_name
  attr_accessible :description, :number, :customer_name
  belongs_to :customer

  validates_presence_of :number
  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_presence_of :customer_name

  before_save :save_customer
  after_find :find_customer
  after_destroy :destroy_customer

  protected

  def save_customer
    if self.customer
      self.customer.name = self.customer_name
    else
      self.customer = Customer.create(name: self.customer_name)
    end
    self.customer.save
  end

  def find_customer
    self.customer_name = self.customer.name
  end

  def destroy_customer
    self.customer.destroy
  end
end
```

Example grid for Order model.

```
class Orders < Netzke::Basepack::Grid
  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = 'Order'
    c.items = [
      :description,
      :number,
      :customer_name
    ]
    c.enable_edit_inline = false
    c.enable_add_inline = false
  end

  def preconfigure_record_window(c)
    super
    c.form_config.klass = OrderForm
  end
end
```

Example form for Order model.

```
class OrderForm< Netzke::Basepack::Form
  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = 'Order'
    c.items = [
      :description,
      :number,
      :customer_name
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. But I was asking about rails default method to do this task. This can be done with creating virtual attributes and passing the values to default association. Your answer helped me to understand the process in a different way.